# Why gevent's join() of one greenlet runs all other greenlets?

Tags: python, gevent

Consider following example:

```py
import gevent

def anna():
    while True:
        print('anna')
        gevent.sleep(0)

def bob():
    while True:
        print('bob')
        gevent.sleep(0)

task1 = gevent.spawn(anna)
task2 = gevent.spawn(bob)
task1.join()
```

When you run it, it prints both anna and bob.

Why so? And how to unschedule `task2` from run, until `task1` is done?

Comment: Joining one Greelet has no effect on others. They will just continue normally. If you don't want concurrency, why do you use greenlets? And how do you expect `bob()` or `anna()` to finish?

Comment: I'm using greenlet because I want some tasks to run in order and some tasks in parallel.  Like advanced pipeline. I'm trying to understand what join actually do. And if I modify my run part as `task1.join(0.1); task2.join(2)` - it continues to run both greenlets. I thought anna is killed when join times out, but it doesn't happen. So what `join` do in this case?

Comment: `join()` lets the current thread or greenlet wait for the given thread or greenlet to finish (the function returns or raises an exception). This will never happen in your endless loop though.